# ssh: connect to host * port 22: Connection timedout

Tags: windows, ubuntu, git, ssh

Я соеденила свой Ubuntu с Windows через ssh.
В файле hosts по пути C:/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/ я написала IP (который получила через ifconfig на Ubuntu) и имя хоста. Опускаю подробности вроде генерации ключа.
Мой laptop с Ubuntu и стационар с WindowsXP подключены к одному Wi-Fi.
Однако когда другой человек из моей команды попробовал подключиться через ssh к laptop-у, будучи подключённым к другому провайдеру, он получил ошибку связанную с timeout-ом, которую вы можете видеть выше.
После чего я попробовала изменить IP, на, насколько я понимаю - глобальный, взятый с сайта ifconfig.me . IP в итоге вышли разные(ifconfig в консоли и ifconfig.me).

Насколько я понимаю, это как то связано с тем что laptop не даёт подключиться другому ПК.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105930/discussion-on-question-by-anna-d-ssh-connect-to-host-port-22-connection-tim).